# show HEAD in magit log

Tags: emacs, terminal, magit, 256color

I would like to know if there is a way to alter the way Magit highlight the current checked out branch on the magit-log. `git log --decorate` will show the `HEAD` at the checked out commit and Magit show an `@` when checking out a commit (with no branch), but, when a branch is checked out, the branch name is enclosed in a rectangle as shown below:

[image]

However, when running emacs from a terminal, the same checked out branch will appear as:

[image]

As you can see, it is not possible to identify the current checked out branch from.

I tried to `customize-face` but this did not work...

Thank you for the help,
Lorenzo

Comment: I recommend that you ask questions about Emacs, and especially Magit, on http://emacs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Customize `magit-branch-current` so that it differs from `magit-branch-local`. The difference obviously has to involve a property which actually has an effect in a terminal, such as the foreground color.

Comment: Note also that you can specify face properties on a per display type basis when you customize. So, if desirable, you could leave the GUI version as-is, but specify terminal-only properties. In the Customize Face UI, under the "State" menu, select "For all kinds of displays", and then you can INSert a new entry with a "Display" option of "specific display", and configure accordingly...

Comment: so modifying the face is the only way to highlight the current branch? Would it not be possible to show ``HEAD`` just as in ``git log --decorate``?

Comment: A line `abcdef HEAD some-branch some new feature` is ambiguous. It doesn't tell you whether `some-branch` is checked out, or whether `HEAD` is detached and just happens to point to the same commit as `some-branch`.